# Trying to remove a pod with CocoaPods 0.36 Beta2

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods with swift, therefor I need a pre release. I'm not sure whether I found a bug or maybe it's just a wrong thing I do.

If I want to remove a pod, I simly remove it from the podfile and call pod install again.

This works, but afterwards, the remaining frameworks are not recognized as frameworks anymore.

Is this the right way to remove pods and am I missing something? E.g. cleaning up my workspace or so?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to restore your project to the original state, you should use this utility: https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate .  Your problem statement is a little ambiguous though - the remaining frameworks are not recognized.  Do you have a greater problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: well, this is the greatest problem I currently have..

Comment: by the way, I don't want to remove all the pods.. I want to remove a specific pod..

Comment: The simplest approach is to nuke the Pods directory, I generally just type `rm -rf Pods && pod install`.  You might have had dangling projects, I am not sure from your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

@Christian, removing from Podfile and running `pod install` at the command line should work. It sounds like a bug.

Can you post one or more errors about the frameworks so we have more to work with? Also, you should consider reporting it.